# A Little Explanation Over Database And SQL

Tags: sql, database

I would like to know how  sites like Facebook (over 900 million users), Twitter (over 300 million users) etc... are able to select a user's login name and password from the database to check if the login credentials a user has entered is correct. For instance in SQL you use :

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE username=[username from user] 
  and password = [password from user]
```

but in bigger systems like Facebook, do they select all the 900 million users and check the login credentials of a single user when a user is login in? If not then what do they do?

**PS :**

Am asking because I am new in this area. I know SQL but want to know how systems with millions of users check the login credentials of their users and other related situations where users are searching for some specific information from the site.

Comment: 1: They do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: No.  You need to learn about indices.  If you are interested in performance, you should also learn about in-memory databases and parallelsim.

Comment: Sites as big as those don't just use a database: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3479720/1073063)

Comment: Most DB systems can handle millions of records and find a single line rediculously efficicently as long as it was setup correctly

Comment: @Pablo If they don't use just database, what do they use then in addition? Tell me more

Comment: @Pablo Actually, as far as simple authentication is concerned, they likely do just rely on a well-indexed database.

Comment: I want to thank all you guys for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is how tables are queried. This is what SQL is for, efficiently querying large sets of data.

A properly [indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) column can be ordered/filtered extremely efficiently. The database is not performing a linear search of 900 million records, it will use some kind of optimized [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Assuming a perfectly balanced binary tree, the worst case for searching through 900,000,000 would require only **30** comparisons, which is the log2 of 900,000,000.

Comment: So when it comes to login, there is no need to use search engines like Lucene, Solr etc..? OR ?

Comment: @EddyFreeman No, absolutely not. Those are for performing "full text" searches. That is, searching against large blobs of text that can't be easily stored in short fixed-length strings. They are not useful in any way for searching against a short single-word column like a username.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. From what i have read from you and the comments so far it means that i have to do the database indexing myself. I mean the indexing feature is not built into the database systems(MySQL, Postgre etc...) automatically  Am i right?

Comment: No. Indexing is built into practically *every* database. It's fundamentally integral to the design of databases and SQL. MySQL and PostgreSQL both implement a variety of indexes. You do not have to "do it yourself", you simply specify indexes on the columns you're going to be search/sorting against. Your database software is responsible for building and maintaining the index, and using it when a query involves an indexed column. You only need to specify which columns should be included in which index. Any tutorial on creating database tables should tell you how to do this.